# How to get number of active connections using BasicDataSource object in java

Tags: java, database-connection, datasource, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I am trying to get the number of active connections using BasicDataSource object like following

```
BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
bds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
bds.setUrl(url);
bds.setUsername(username);
bds.setPassword(password);
```

and returning various values in json like

```
resourceObject.put("MaxTotal", bds.getMaxTotal());
resourceObject.put("NumActive", bds.getNumActive());
resourceObject.put("NumIdle", bds.getNumIdle());
```

I am always getting 0 for the number active and number idle, is there any other thing I forgot to set. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that your JdbcTemplate, or Spring Data repositories or whatever using exactly this datasouce in order to retrieve connections?) Becuase, for example, Spring Boot by default is using HikariDataSource (just to double check)

I cannot address BasicDataSource, but I can show how one can do it with HikariDataSource:

```
hikariDataSource.getHikariPoolMXBean().getActiveConnections();
hikariDataSource.getHikariPoolMXBean().getIdleConnections();
```

I know, that this does not answer the original question, but at least, maybe it will help someone.